# Entity framework async mehods suddenly throws exception after iis recycle

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, asynchronous

Starting yesterday morning, after our nightly site recycle at 03:00 UTC, entity framework throws `NullReferenceException` on different kinds of async method calls (`CountAsync`, `ToArrayAsync` etc).

No code or configuration change have occurred (according to Git logs) and the server itself haven't been running any automatic updates to itself or so.

**And now, i have no idea what i can be that causes this kind of behavior, any ideas?**

Tried the following

- Redploy existing code
- Restart
- Windows updates
- New site

Works on the test server which we deployed production to (servers are Windows Server 2012 R2, all hosted on AWS).

Switching to non-async method fix the problem, but not doable everywhere at this moment.

Stacktrace for the notifications controller, but same behavior on the jobs controller and some more.

```
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.<StoreReadAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<SingleAsync>d__2d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Web.Notifications.AlertService.UnmappedCheck`4.<Check>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Web.Notifications.AlertService.<Check>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Web.ApiControllers.NotificationsController.<Count>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of testing and search, we found the culprit being the `SetExecutionStrategy` when used in conjuction with webapi and async calls to the database.

We use this approach for some time to set the strategy in certain cases:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn307226.aspx#transactions_workarounds

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public MyConfiguration() 
    { 
        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy 
          ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy() 
          : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy()); 
    } 
  
    public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy") ?? false; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Why this caused the error, and not until recently after a normal recycle, i still have no answers for.